# How can I determine if a light switch shorted out?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, light-fixture

I have a light that's controlled by 2 switches. I rewired one of them recently. I tested it and it worked after I did so.

Now, the light isn't turning on anymore when I flip the switch. When I use the other switch, it doesn't do anything either.

I would change the bulb to check but, unfortunately, the base that the bulb screws into is loose. So, it's essentially impossible to change the bulb (and I can't repair it either). The bulb doesn't appear to be burned out.

I checked my new switch and everything appears to look right but I can't say for sure. Everything is also still getting voltage. Does this sound like it shorted out or an issue with the light itself?

Comment: Turn off the breaker to this fixture and use your voltage tester to determine that the power is off. Repair or replace the fixture. If you have to have the fixture out for a while, but need the other lights or receptacles on the circuit, put wire nuts on the individual wires (But do not connect the wires that went to the fixture. This would be a short and would trip the breaker.) Turn the beaker back on so you can use this circuit.

Comment: Are you getting electricity at the switches?

Comment: I'm planning on doing that soon, I just need to buy a new fixture. Yes @ThreePhaseEel.

Comment: If the base is loose, that certainly explains why the lamp failed.